# trying a custom computation of grid.best_score_ (obtained with GridSearchCV)

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to recompute `grid.best_score_` I obtained on my own data without success...
So I tried it using a conventional dataset but no more success. Here is the code :

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn import grid_search
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

import numpy as np

lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
boston = datasets.load_boston()
target = boston.target
param_grid = {'fit_intercept':[False]}
cv = ShuffleSplit(target.size, n_iter=5, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)
grid = grid_search.GridSearchCV(lr, param_grid, cv=cv)
grid.fit(boston.data, target)
# got cv score computed by gridSearchCV :
print grid.best_score_
```

0.677708680059

```
# now try a custom computation of cv score
cv_scores = []
for (train, test) in cv:
    y_true = target[test]
    y_pred = grid.best_estimator_.predict(boston.data[test,:])
    cv_scores.append(r2_score(y_true, y_pred))

print np.mean(cv_scores)
```

0.703865991851

I can't see why it's different, `GridSearchCV` is supposed to use scorer from LinearRegression, which is r2 score. Maybe the way I code `cv` score is not the one used to compute `best_score_`... I'm asking here before going through GridSearchCV code.

Answer (score 2):

Unless `refit=False` in the `GridSearchCV` constructor, the winning estimator is refit on the entire dataset at the end of `fit`. `best_score_` is the estimator's average score using the cross-validation splits, while `best_estimator_` is an estimator of the winning configuration fit on *all* the data.

```
lr2 = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
scores2 = [lr2.fit(boston.data[train,:], target[train]).score(boston.data[test,:], target[test])
           for train, test in cv]
print np.mean(scores2)
```

Will print `0.67770868005943297`.